# (element).append in child dropdown not working javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-core

i have three dropdown menus and two are appending  and poping up successful which is(dropCountries,dropProvince) except the third one dropArea,my controller returns the data successfully when doing console.log but does not append to the "#dropArea" part/element,is there a possible reason why it could be doing this?

Javascript

```
<script>
    function showProvinces(id) {
       // var cId = id.value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/GetProvinces?countryId=" + id,
            datatdataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i) {
                   //this append works
                    $("#dropProvince").append("<a class='" + "dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" + "' href='" + "#" + "' id='" +
                        "multilevelDropdownMenu2" + "' data-bs-toggle='" + "dropdown" + "' aria-haspopup='" + "true" +
                        "'aria-expanded='" + "false" + "' onmouseover='" + "ShowAreas(" + data[i].id + ")" + "'>" + data[i].name + "</a>");
                });
            }
        })
    }
    function ShowAreas(id) {
        /*  var cId = id.value;*/
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/GetAreas?provinceId=" + id,
            datatdataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i) {
                   //console.log(data[i].name) data appearing
                  //append not working
                    $("#dropArea").append("<a class='" + "dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" + "' href='" + "#" + "' id='" +
                        "multilevelDropdownMenu3" + "' data-bs-toggle='" + "dropdown" + "' aria-haspopup='" + "true" +
                        "'aria-expanded='" + "false" + "'>" + data[i].name + "</a>");
                });
            }
        })
    }

 $(document).ready(function () {
 let dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle')
        dropdowns.forEach((dd) => {
            dd.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
                var el = this.nextElementSibling
                el.style.display = el.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block'
            })
            dd.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
                var el = this.nextElementSibling
                el.style.display = el.style.display === 'block' ? 'block' : 'none'
            })
        })
        //load countries in sub menu
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/GetCountries",
            datatdataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i) {
                //this append works
                    $("#dropCountries").append("<a class='" + "dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" + "' href='" + "#" + "' data-bs-toggle='" + "dropdown" + "' aria-haspopup='" + "true" +
                        "'  aria-expanded='" + "false" + "' onmouseover='" + "showProvinces(" + data[i].id + ")" + "'>" + data[i].name + "</a>");
                });
                //let item = document.getElementById("multilevelDropdownMenu1");
                //item.addEventListener('mouseover', function () { showProvinces(data[i].id); })
            }
        })

</script>
```

HTML

```
   <li id="quickNavBtn" class="nav-item dropdown text-dark">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="quickNavDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Quick Nav
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" >
                            <li class="dropdown dropright" id="dropCountries">
                               
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" id="dropProvince1" style="display:block">
                                    <li class="dropdown dropright" id="dropProvince">
                             
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" id="dropArea1" style="display:block">
                                            <li class="dropdown dropright" id="dropArea">
                                               
                                            </li>

                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                            </li>            
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Comment: Did you return the data correctly in the dropArea column you requested? There is an error in my code using your code. Is there an error in the console on your side?

Comment: Hi @Chaodeng,the data is returned and i can see all names in the console(please check commented Console.Log(data[i].name))  the problem is appending it to "dropArea" in the html,the third dropdown does not appear